# Sum Method / for-loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, sum

It may be a stupid question for you, but I´m pretty much of a scrub when it comes to java.
I want write a method `public int sum()` which is going through my list and **returns total number of visitors**.

I dont get what I´m supposed to write in my for-loop. I tried "length" and so on, but it wasn´t working for a reason.

```
      import java.util.*;
          public class VisitorList {
                BesucherTag head;
                BesucherTag z;

            public class VisitorDay {
            public int day;
            public int month;
            public int year;    
            public int number;
            VisitorDay next = null;

            public VisitorDay(int day, int month, int year, int number){
                this.day = day;
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;
                this.number = number;
            }
    }

                public VisitorList(){
                head = new VisitorDay(0,0,0,0);
                z = new VisitorDay(0,0,0,0);
                head.next = z;
                z.next = z;
                }

                public int sum(){
                    for(int i = 0; i <= "?!" ; i++){

                    }
}
```

Comment: What list is it supposed to traverse? I don't see any list.

Comment: I suppose you could traverse your structure using `while(head.next != null) { count++; head = head.next; }`

Comment: Isn´t this some kind of a linkedlist? I´m not sure, but i know that I´m not supposed to generate a arraylist or something else. This are the method´s/classes I´m supposed to work with :S

Comment: Your question makes no sense in the context of the code you've provided. What list is the method supposed to run through?

Comment: @Lauri Elias ah yep. I guess that would work. So i create a local variable "count=0;" before, right?

U got a Idea how I sum the numbers of visitor. I dont know how to sum only 1 attribute of "VisitorDay"

Comment: @peeskillet ... I thought this is a Linkedlist. I´m sorry if i can´t provide u with more informations. As i said I´m pretty much of a beginner. But actually it should make sense in  the context of the code, because this is all I´ve been provided with / I wrote until now.

Comment: It´s supposed to return the total number of Visitors in this context.

Comment: Look an my answer. I think its something along the lines of what is required. The `sum` method should go in the `VisitorList` class. The class contains an array of `VisitorDay`s and that's where you get the sum from.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create your own linked list implementation called `VisitorList`. You should probably just use `java.util.LinkedList<VisitorDay>`. Then you would traverse the list:

```
java.util.List<VisitorDay> listOfVisitors = new java.util.LinkedList<VisitorDay>();

//code which adds your visitors

//now the loop
for(VisitorDay vd : listOfVisitors){
    count++;
}
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: Okay. The problem is I got some kind of a worksheet and there is nothing mentiones like this :/ I guess I´m generating some "VisitorDay´s" in a main method later on and then i just have to add their numbers. But just their numbers. As long as the "VisitorDay´s" are all part of the class "VisitorList" it should work without arrays shouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement you own LinkedList, you'll want something like this. If you cant use Lists, then use an array. that's how Lists are implemented under the hood. You'll also need to implement some sort of `addVisitorDay` method that adds to the `dayList` and auto-increases in size if the capacity is reached.

The `sum` method should go in the `VisitorList` class. The class contains an array of `VisitorDay`s and that's where you get the sum from.

```
public class VisitorList {

    public static final CAPACITY = 10;
    VisitorDay[] dayList = new VisitorDay[CAPACITY];  

    public int sum(){
        int sum = 0;
        for (VisitorDay vd : dayList){
            sum += vd.getNumber();
        }
        return sum;
    }  
}

public class VisitorDay{
    private number;

    public getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

**Edit: Forget everything else on top**

```
public class VisitorDay {
        public int day;
        public int month;
        public int year;
        public int number;    

        public static sum = 0;

        public VisitorDay(int day, int month, int year, int number){
            this.day = day;
            this.month = month;
            this.year = year;
            this.number = number;
            sum += number;
        }

        public int sum(){
            return sum;
        }
}
```

Since the field `sum` is `static` everytime you create a `VisitorDay` object, the sum will increase. Whenever you want to get the sum, just call the `sum()` method and you will have your sum.

Comment: Okay. The problem is I got some kind of a worksheet and there is nothing mentioned like this :/ 

I guess I´m generating some "VisitorDay´s" in a main method later on and then i just have to add their numbers. But just their numbers. As long as the "VisitorDay´s" are all part of the class "VisitorList" it should work without arrays shouldnt it?

Comment: Did the assignment require a `VisitorList` and a `VisitorDay`? And did it require a `sum` method? There are many ways to accomplish your task. But I want to advise you on the most acceptible way for your assinment.

Comment: yep. Everything should be alright except for that method :/
I´m supposed to write exactly this method. A "sum" method which is adding the number of visitors of several days. There isn´t even mentioned a "get" method to get the number. If i would need it, it would have been mentioned.

Comment: Does the assigment say where the sum method should be?

Comment: oh, well. It´s outside of the "VisitorDay" class :/ my bad. Does that change anything?

Comment: But I´m really not supposed to generate an array. Cause later on I´m working with 

VisitorList bList = new VisitorList();

in another class.

Comment: Ok so let me get this completely straight. Your `VisitorList` class. Is that the class you want to run the program from. You want that class to have the `main` method?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to cheat a little, since I don't think the assigment specifies not to do this. Wait a bit.

Comment: Later on I have to write another class which is generating a "VisitorList" like I mentioned in the comment before. I havn´t written that class yet, so I don´t know what that one is doing, but if I needed a array or something it would have been mentioned in the tasks for this class.

Comment: I gotta go to sleep. It's late where I'm at. You got your sum method. Works just fine. I'll keep my original post up, in case you find out you're supposed to implement your own List functionality.